# What is the maximum number of hearts you can get?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

In Zelda: A Link to the Past, it is possible to get additional hearts by completing dungeons (which gives you a full heart), by finding very rare full hearts out in the game world, and by collecting pieces of heart in order to create a new, full heart.

What is the maximum number of hearts you can get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 24 heart pieces, yielding 20 max hearts total.

Their locations are shown in detail [here](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda03-a-link-to-the-past-heart-pieces.php).

Comment: This tells you how many heart pieces there are, but it doesn't actually tell you what the maximum number of hearts actually *is*.

Comment: @fbueckert good point, edited.

Answer (score 0):

I recall 3 hearts at the beginning, a full heart after you rescue zelda,(four), a full heart for each pendant,(7),a full heart for each crystal, (14), and each row was even, so I believe 20 is correct , leaving 6 hearts to heart pieces, or 24 pieces.